# Validation error after Mongoose version update: owner.$populated is not a function

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

After updating to last version of Mongoose (`6.6.1`), the .save() of a Document now raises an error, while before was saving without problems.
It's about the validation of a field, marked as `Date`, but it seems ok to me. Anyway I get the error `owner.$populated is not a function`.

What's the problem? And why the error talks about `owner`field?

**This is the Object**

```
 new MyTask({
        "source": {
                    "client_id" : "ABC",
                    "ip"        : "127.0.0.1"
                  },
       "invoice": {
                    "amount"    : 1000,
                    "currency"  : "eur",
                    "dueAt"     : "2022-10-23T14:55:57.482Z",
                    "issuedAt"  : "2022-07-25T13:55:57.480Z",
                    "number"    : "724/001"        
                  }
    }).save();
```

---

**This is the Schema**

```
var invoice_schema = new Schema({
                "amount"   : {type:Number,    required:true},
                "currency" : {type:String,    required:true}, 
                "dueAt"    : {type:Date,      required:true}, 
                "issuedAt" : {type:Date,      required:true},
                "number"   : {type:String}                    
                                },
               {
                timestamps:true,
                toObject  : { virtuals: true },
                toJSON    :   { virtuals: true }  
               });

var MYTASK_SCHEMA = new Schema(
  {
   source : {
              ip         : {type: String},
              client_id  : {type: String}
             },        
   invoice: {type        : invoice_schema}
  },
  {
   timestamps:true,
   toObject: { virtuals: true },
   toJSON  : { virtuals: true }  
  });
```

---

**And this is the error:**

```
Error: MyTask validation failed: 
          invoice.dueAt: owner.$populated is not a function, 
          invoice.issuedAt: owner.$populated is not a function, 
          invoice: Validation failed: 
              dueAt: owner.$populated is not a function, 
              issuedAt: owner.$populated is not a function
    at ValidationError.inspect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:48:26)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:790:19)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:350:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2241:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2103:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:348:14)
    at console.warn (node:internal/console/constructor:381:61)
```

Comment: I am trying locally, and it seems working... on heroku, I got that error. In both cases, I'm using the same DB remote instance

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: Is there anything that `owner.$populated` could mean?

Comment: I think I found the problem. I added an answer to my post

Answer (score 1):

after some checks, I found that one of the packages listed in package.json, have a dependency with an older version of mongoose.
I found this doing

```
$npm list mongoose

servers@1.0.0 /app
    +-- @mypackage/api_core@1.0.36
    | +-- @mypackage/misc@1.0.29
    | | `-- mongoose@6.6.1 deduped
    | +-- @mypackage/task@1.0.21
    | | `-- mongoose@5.8.11      /* <-- this one broke everything */
    | `-- @mypackage/user@1.0.12
    |   `-- mongoose@6.6.1 deduped
    +-- @mypackage/auth@1.0.6
    | +-- @mypackage/bank@1.0.14
    | | `-- mongoose@6.6.1 deduped
```

Updating that package to use the last version of Mongoose, seems worked!